# Mongo Java Driver find method deprecated

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I wanted to use the following method of mongo java driver.\

```
db.<collection>.find(DBObject query,DBObject param,int skip,int batchSize,int option)
```

but I found this method is deprecated, so what else can be used,as I am interested in doing read operation by setting preferences.

if i use the following:

```
List<ServerAddress> seeds = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
seeds .add(seed1);
seeds .add(seed2);

MongoClient test= new MongoClient(seeds);
```

and later point of time if i do

```
test.setReadPreference(preference);
```

is it going to set my read preference?

Comment: which version of mongo jar are you using?

Comment: As answered by @parvin , it would work for u.

Comment: @Jhanvi,I am more interested in setting preferences in MongoClient.And if its possible, than my concern is if I reset the preference with setReadPrefernce() after calling getDB(),is it going to reset the preference? –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the read preference on multiple levels: the client, the database, the collection and finally on individual query.

If you set the read preference on the MongoClient with

```
mongoClient.setReadPreference(secondary());
```

then this is the default read preference that will be used for all queries, unless you define otherwise.  You need to ensure you set this *before* running any queries, or it will not take effect.

If you set a read preference on a collection using:

```
collection.setReadPreference(primary());
```

this would override your MongoClient settings, and the primary would be used by default when accessing this collection (see [this blog post](http://metabroadcast.com/blog/mutant-objects-a-lesson-in-why-immutability-is-good) as well to understand how read preferences work at a collection level.

Finally, you could further override the preference for some individual queries, like the methods you found that are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

[DBCursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.3/) has `skip()`, `batchSize()` and `setOptions()` methods. You can use them as follows :

```
db.<collection>find(DBObject query,DBObject param).skip(int skip).batchSize(int batchSize).setOptions(int options);
```

Comment: ,I am more interested in setting preferences in MongoClient.And if its possible, than my concern is if I reset the preference with setReadPrefernce() after calling getDB(),is it going to reset the preference?